# Why do Eagle CAD diodes not work like normal components in a schematic?

Tags: eaglecad

I'm drawing schematics in Eagle CAD and diodes don't behave like normal components:

a) Most diodes have the text "Spice Order" attached to the wires, which makes my schematics look really strange.

b) I found a diode under "docu-dummy", but the wires don't attach to the diode. If I move the diode, the wires get left behind.

Other symbols all work normally, but I can't find a normal diode. Is there a diode symbol that works like all the others?

[image: a diode symbol labeled 1N4004. Purple text "Spice Order 1" overlaps one end and "Spice Order 2" overlaps the other end.]

Comment: Maybe you can turn off those layers or edit the library and delete/reposition the text if it bothers you.